# Convert .tex to .docx using pandoc when using the mchem package

Tags: pandoc, mhchem

I use `pandoc` to convert `.tex` file to `.docx`.

However, the document is not converted properly when it uses the package `mhchem`.
Indeed, I then get this error:

```
  unexpected "{"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
  [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 'I = z \cdot F \cdot \frac{A \cdot D \cdot S}{d} \cdot p(\ce{O2})', rendering as TeX:
  t S}{d} \cdot p(\ce{O2})
                     ^
```

How do I solve that?

---

- I'm using documentclass svmono (Springer template)
- with packages asmath, mhchem, mathptx
- I have a master file, with 11 subfiles with \include
- the chemistry part is with mhchem
- that where the problem starts:

For example:
`Verschiedene Schmerzmediatoren wie ATP, \ce{H+} (abgegeben von geschädigten Zellen) und Prostaglandine (z.B. PGE2) stimulieren die Nozizeptoren`
 - is my code; in the docx file everything is shown except for H+ :

### Verschiedene Schmerzmediatoren wie ATP, (abgegeben von geschädigten Zellen) und Prostaglandine (z.B. PGE2) stimulieren die Nozizeptoren

tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    Hello world\\
    \ce{H+} and ATP to convert.
\end{document}
```

cmd:

```
C:\Users\nivit>cd Desktop

C:\Users\nivit\Desktop>pandoc convert.tex -o convert.docx

C:\Users\nivit\Desktop>
```

And that's how my docx file look like: The H+ is not there anymore 
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without code. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added more infos in de description

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a screenshot of your errors, try to construct a minimal compilable document that can allow others to reproduce your error. This will obviously not be your actual document, but a new self-contained document that has only as much code as is needed to reproduce the error. Then edit your question to include *that* document (not a screenshot.)

Comment: you can convert your document to ODT using `make4ht -f odt convert.tex`. It seems to work on your sample file.